# ListView in activity with other widgets

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I'm building an app which I'd like to add a `ListView` to an activity not a listActivity but the activity also contains other widget controls. Iv tried doing it but it doesn't look good at all. Here is the xml that created the `ListView` in my activity:

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/experienceList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp" >
    </ListView>
```

Unfortunately stackoverflow didn't allow me to post a image. But the `ListView` doesn't reveal all its contents. how can I make the `ListView` reveal all and just stretch it out, the root of the activity is a scrollView so it should probably work the way i want it.

Comment: but stackoverflow does allow posting code of (for example) your usage of the adapter and/or your custom layout-file of your listadapter :)

Comment: I did post the xml code that created the view, if you want me to post any other code i will pls, just ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a scrollable (ListView) inside another one (ScrollView) will not work, for obvious reasons. Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing) for more details, answered by Google's very own Romain Guy. Replace your ListView by a LinearLayout ...